# Error with params in Pandas read_sql_query

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I have a simple SQl query and i want to use params, but it returns a database error when I add the param. If I change the dynamic param to a fixed value, it works.

My code is quite simple:

```
sql = """ SELECT p.description, SUM(p.price) as price
          FROM product p
          WHERE p.extenal_id = ?
          GROUP BY p.description """

result = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=conn, params=[202101])
```

The error is:

> SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "GROUP"
> LINE 4:           p.external_id = ? GROUP BY p.description...

The problem can't be the query since if I change the ? by 202101 and remove the params in read_sql_query it works.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Google Colab

Comment: are you sure the database you are querying uses `?` for parameter notation

Answer (score 0):

#use f-string is better

```
params=[202101]

sql = f""" SELECT p.description, SUM(p.price) as price
          FROM product p
          WHERE p.extenal_id = {params}
          GROUP BY p.description """

result = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=conn)
```

#use tuple for more items

```
params=tuple([202101, 202102, 202103])

sql = f""" SELECT p.description, SUM(p.price) as price
          FROM product p
          WHERE p.extenal_id in {params}
          GROUP BY p.description """
result = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=conn)
```

Comment: Thanks!
If I need to use it as string list param inside a IN clause, should I change something?

I'm trying to do that, but it's not putting the simple quote, example:

params = ('abc', 'def')

If I print the query after apply f-string, it shows:
IN (abc, def)

Comment: Besides, is that true that f-string is not recommended because it allow SQL injection?